# Salesforce Button: How To Display An Error if Opportunity Stage Does Not Equal "Closed Won"

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

I'm creating a DocuSign custom button within Salesforce. Attempting to add an error when some field values are not met before running the DocuSign button logic.

My desired condition is if the pick list value of Opportunity Stage does not equal "Closed Won" THEN trigger an error message. else, execute the DocuSign custom button.

I am very new to javascript and just started learning, so I apologize for the elementary questions and appreciate the feedback.

My current script is below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")}

var oppStage = "Closed Won";
var error;
{
if ({!Opportunity.StageName}!=oppStage)

{
error = "Unable to send envelope. Opportunity Stage does not equal Closed won.";
}
else {
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//

CES="Hello World";

CRL='FirstName~{!URLENCODE(User.FirstName)};LastName~{!URLENCODE(User.LastName)};Email~{!URLENCODE(User.Email)};Role~OppOwner;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';

CCRM='Business User~Signer 1;OppOwner~Signer 2';

LA='0';

CEM='Hello World,\\n\\nThis should be a double line break.';


//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
}
}
```

The current error message I receive is *"Qualification is not defined"*.

Qualification is the current value of the pick list on my Opportunity. If I change this value, the error message will reflect it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revised code now triggers the desired behavior I was seeking:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")}

var oppStage = "Closed Won";
var OpptyStage = '{!Opportunity.StageName}';
if (OpptyStage!=oppStage)
{
alert("Unable to send envelope. Opportunity Stage does not equal Closed won.");
}
else {
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//

CES="Hello World";

CRL='FirstName~{!URLENCODE(User.FirstName)};LastName~{!URLENCODE(User.LastName)};Email~{!URLENCODE(User.Email)};Role~OppOwner;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';

CCRM='Business User~Signer 1;OppOwner~Signer 2';

LA='0';

CEM='Hello World,\\n\\nThis should be a double line break.';


//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
}
```